# Validation is not working with user input controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, validation

I used validation on my `aspx` page, but it doesn't work and there is no error

```
<div class="fourm-container">                         
    <div class="single-input">
        <span>email</span>
        <input name="" type="text" runat="server" id="email" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVemail" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="email" Display="Dynamic"
            ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
            ValidationGroup="one"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="login" name="submit" 
            onclick="AddCustomer" runat="server" validationgroup="one" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the form tag and the closing div, I tried this snippet and could see the validation happening. (without the onclick) if you see it working, then the onclick has an issue.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="fourm-container">
        <div class="single-input">
            <span>email</span>
            <input name="" type="text" runat="server" id="email" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVemail" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="email" Display="Dynamic"
                ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                ValidationGroup="one"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="login" name="submit" runat="server" validationgroup="one" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ValidationGroup="one"` in `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Try it:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVemail" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="email" Display="Dynamic"
                ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```